# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'DataFrame', store data from flask form to postgresql database

Tags: python, database, flask, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to create a Flask form able to parse a csv and store value in postgresql database.

I use following library : pandas, psycopg2, sqlalchemy.

After few hours wondering how, I'm not able to fix the following error :

"AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'"

Can someone help me out ?

Thanks a lot fam

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import os
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath
import sqlalchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

# Upload folder
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/files'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://doadmin:mypassword@myurl:25060/defaultdb')

# db_cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS leads(
#          Category,
#          Platform,
#          Job,
#          Firstname,
#          Lastname,
#          Company, Phone,
#          Mobile,
#          Email,
#          Linkedin,
#          Street,
#          Zipcode,
#          City,
#          Department)""")
# conn.commit()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/uploaded')
def uploaded():
    return render_template('valid_upload.html')


# Get the uploaded files
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def uploadFiles():
    # get the uploaded file
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    if uploaded_file.filename != '':
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], uploaded_file.filename)
        # set the file path
        uploaded_file.save(file_path)
        # call parseCSV function
        parseCSV(file_path)
    # save the file
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


def parseCSV(filePath):
    # CVS Column Names
    col_names = ['Category', 'Platform', 'Job', 'Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Company', 'Phone', 'Mobile', 'Email',
                 'Linkedin', 'Street', 'Zipcode', 'City', 'Department']
    # Use Pandas to parse the CSV file
    csvData = pd.read_csv(filePath, names=col_names, header=None)
    print(csvData.to_string())
    # Loop through the Rows
    for i, row in csvData.iterrows():
        sql = "INSERT INTO leads(Category, Platform, Job, Firstname, Lastname, Company, Phone, Mobile, Email, Linkedin, Street, Zipcode, City, Department) VALUES( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        value = (row['Category'], row['Platform'], row['Job'], row['Firstname'], row['Lastname'], row['Company'],
                 row['Phone'], row['Mobile'], row['Email'], row['Linkedin'], row['Street'], row['Zipcode'], row['City'],
                 row['Department'])

        print(i, row['Category'], row['Platform'], row['Job'], row['Firstname'], row['Lastname'], row['Company'],
              row['Phone'], row['Mobile'], row['Email'], row['Linkedin'], row['Street'], row['Zipcode'], row['City'],
              row['Department'])
        df = pd.DataFrame([value],
                          columns=['Category', 'Platform', 'Job', 'Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Company', 'Phone', 'Mobile',
                                   'Email',
                                   'Linkedin', 'Street', 'Zipcode', 'City', 'Department'])
        df.to_sql('leads', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

        df = value.DataFrame(c.fetchall(),
                             columns=['Category', 'Platform', 'Job', 'Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Company', 'Phone',
                                      'Mobile', 'Email',
                                      'Linkedin', 'Street', 'Zipcode', 'City', 'Department'])
        print(df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: `df = value.DataFrame` value is a tuple, just like the error message says.  Perhaps you meant `df = pd.dataFrame` instead?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146 and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to *read* and *understand* error messages that are given to you.